# vue js dynamiccaly rearrange children of a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a vue component with children as below , id like to rearrange the children when a certain event occurs , how would i chieve this ?

**app.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
       <child-one></child-one>
       <child-two></child-two>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
   module.exports = {

      components: {
         'child-one' : require('./child1.vue'),
         'child-two' : require('./child2.vue')

      },
    events: {
         'rearrange': function (d) { 
            // dynamically rearrange 'child-one' and 'child-two'
          }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to manipulate them dynamically, it's probably easiest if you generate them dynamically too:

JS:

```
data(){
    return {
        components:[
            {
                type:'child-one'
            },
            {
                type:'child-two'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <div v-for="component in components" :is="component.type"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then in your event you can just manipulate the `components` array however you need to

Comment: if its his answer too then it is definitely correct